# What does @Secured({ "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN" }) exactly means

Tags: java, spring, security, annotations, role

I have come accross the following annotation in my example code.

```
@Secured({ "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN" })
```

Could anyone explain what doest it mean?

Comment: This can also be helpful: http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-security-method-level.jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Spring Security Framework annotation to allow the method to be executed only when the caller has either `ROLE_USER` or `ROLE_ADMIN` security roles.

See the [documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) for more information on Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a example:

```
@Controller
public class ProtectedMethodsController {

    @Secured({"ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN"})//->for both security roles
    @RequestMapping("/protectedMethod")
    public @ResponseBody String secretMethod() {
        return "You executed the protected method successfully (For USERs)";
    }

    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    @RequestMapping("/adminProtectedMethod")
    public @ResponseBody String adminSecretMethod() {
        return "You executed the protected method successfully (For ADMINs)";
    }

    //->Without @Secured("ROLE_")
    @RequestMapping("/notProtectedMethod")
    public @ResponseBody String notProtectedMethod() {
        return "You executed the not protected method successfully (For ALL USERs)";
    }

    /** Notes:
     *  1 - The first step is to enable method security, you do that annotating 
     *      the main class (class with the @SpringBootApplication annotation)
     *      with @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true);
     *  2 - Then we can decorate the method resources with @Secured("ROLE_USER") 
     *      annotation.**/

}


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Secured` annotation is a method security in Spring framework. It is one of the **authorization semantics applied at the method level**. It allows the method to be accessed by the user who has atleast one of the roles specified in the `@Secured` annotation.

In the example you have looked into, i.e. `@Secured({ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN})` signifies that the method following this annotation can be accessed  only by someone who has either ROLE_ADMIN or ROLE_USER.

For further reference, go to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security) page.